# elasticsearch wildcard search with and operator

Tags: node.js, wildcard, elasticsearch

I am developing an application that uses elastic search, and in some case I want to make a search that according to term and locales. I am testing this on localhost

```
http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search
```

and parameters

```
query : {
                        wildcard : { "term" : "myterm*" }
                    },
                    filter : {
                        and : [
                            {
                                term : { "lang" : "en" }
                            },
                            {
                                term : { "translations.lang" : "tr" } //this is subdocument search
                            },
                        ]
                    }
```

Here is an example document:

```
{
    "_index": "twitter",
    "_type": "tweet",
    "_id": "5084151d2c6e5d5b11000008",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "lang": "en",
      "term": "photograph",
      "translations": [
        {
          "_id": "5084151d2c6e5d5b11000009",
          "lang": "tr",
          "translation": "fotoğraf",
          "score": "0",
          "createDate": "2012-10-21T15:30:37.994Z",
          "author": "anonymous"
        },
        {
          "_id": "50850346532b865c2000000a",
          "lang": "tr",
          "translation": "resim",
          "score": "0",
          "createDate": "2012-10-22T08:26:46.670Z",
          "author": "anonymous"
        }
      ],
      "author": "anonymous",
      "createDate": "2012-10-21T15:30:37.994Z"
    }
  }
```

I am trying to get terms with wildcard(for autocomplete) with input language "en", and output language "tr". It is getting terms that has "myterm" but doesnt apply, and operation on this. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of what your documents look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to solve my problem with following query;

```
query : {
   wildcard : { "term" : "myterm*" }
},
filter : {
   and : [
      {
         term : { "lang" : "en" }
      },
      {
         term : { "translations.lang" : "tr" } //this is subdocument search
      }
   ]
},
sort : {
   {"term" : "desc"}
}
```

An important point here is, you need to set your sorting field as not_analyzed. Since, you cannot sort a field that is analyzed.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the `translations` element has `nested` type. If this is the case, you should use [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search" -d '{
    query: {
        wildcard: {
            "term": "term*"
        }
    },
    filter: {
        and: [{
            term: {
                "lang": "en"
            }
        }, {
            "nested": {
                "path": "translations",
                "query": {
                    "term" : { "translations.lang" : "tr" }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my document is not nested.Addionally, you need to set your sort field as not_analyzed.